# Need to get data from google spreadsheet to javascript to tie to button

Tags: javascript, json, google-sheets

I am very new to javascript...
I am trying to fetch a url out of a cell in a Google spreadsheet, I would like that url to then be tied to a button on my site...(see button in html below)

```
"<center><FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION= X
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Clickable Button">
</FORM> </center>"
```

I would like the X variable too = the url contain in the specific cell in the Google spreadsheet. I have been searching for days to accomplish this, and I know I need to use some javascript but not sure how to implement it. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

One way you could achieve this is to use [Google JSON API method as documented on this page](https://developers.google.com/gdata/samples/spreadsheet_sample).

You first add a javascript file to your page as the below example.

```
<script src="http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/*ID*/*WS*/public/values?alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=*FN*"></script>
```

• Where ****ID**** is the spreadsheet's long ID.

• Where ****WS**** is the worksheet number e.g. 1,2,3 etc.

• Where ****FN**** is the function you want to call.

Then in the callback function you can do something like the below to add your variable as desired. **rowWithURL** is the row number. **CellWIthURL** is usually the column heading. Or you could use some other methods to locate your URL.

```
function CallBack(json){
   entry = json.feed.entry[rowWithURL];
   url = entry.gsx$CellWithURL.$t;

   content = '<center>' + 
                 '<form method="link" action='+ url +'>' + 
                     '<input type="submit" value="Clickable Button">' +
                 '</form>' +
             '</center>'
}
```

Please note the above is not tested but should get you on the right track.